# passing row number of a listview to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What's wrong with this piece of code?

```
onclick="javascript:myclick('<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>')"
```

I am trying to pass the rowNumber of a listview control to javascript function "myclick". The above code passes all the string "<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" as parameter (without quotes). But I want just the counter (1,2,...)

Any correction/ suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: No, It's a hyperlink tag: <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlProperyLink" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="javascript:myclick('<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>')">

Comment: Cool mate! I was looking for how to send the rownumber just how you were doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ListView's [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) event:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Hyperlink hlProperyLink  = (Hyperlink)e.Item.FindControl("hlProperyLink");
        hlProperyLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:myclick('" + e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString() + "')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim it worked! Just a correction: The e.Item.DataItemIndex needs a .ToString

Answer (score 0):

[Data binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) won't be evaluated unless you call `Page.DataBind();` somewhere in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write all of it in the markup (and not from ItemDataBound), you can use this:

```
onclick='<%#"myClick(" + Container.DataItemIndex +")"%>'
```